# Update no hace nada

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud, update

Uso CodeIgniter y PHP. Al hacer un Update no se muestra mensaje y tampoco se hace la actualización.

**cliente_buscar (controlador):**

```
public function mod(){      
    $mod=$this->main_model->mod(
        $this->input->post("DocIdent"),                                                                        
        $this->input->post("Nombre"),
        $this->input->post("Apellido"),
        $this->input->post("Direccion"),
        $this->input->post("Telefono"),
        $this->input->post("Estado"),
        $this->input->post("FechaIngreso"),
        $this->input->post("Password")
    );

    //si la actualización ha sido correcta creamos una sesión flashdata para decirlo
    if($mod){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('actualizado', 'Usuario modificado correctamente');                
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('incorrecto', 'No se pudo modificar el registro');
    }
}
```

**main_model:**

```
public function mod($DocIdent, $Nombre, $Apellido, $Direccion, $Telefono, $Estado, $FechaIngreso, $Password){   
    $losDatos = array(
        'Nombre' => $Nombre,
        'Apellido' => $Apellido,
        'Direccion' => $Direccion,
        'Telefono' => $Telefono,
        'Estado' => $Estado,
        'FechaIngreso' => $FechaIngreso,
        'Password' => $Password
    );
    $this->db->where('DocIdent', $DocIdent);
    return $this->db->update('tbl_cliente', $losDatos);
    if(is_object($query)){
        if($query->num_rows() == 1) { // if the affected number of rows is one
            return true;
        }
    } else {  
        return false;
    }
}
```

¿Qué debo modificar?

Los datos vienen nulos de esta vista

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Modificar Cliente</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Modificar Cliente</h2>

        <?php echo form_open("cliente_buscar/mod"); ?>         
            <?php foreach ($mod as $fila){ ?>
            <input type="text" name="docIdent" value="<?=$fila->DocIdent?>"/>
            <input type="text"  name="nombre" value="<?=$fila->Nombre?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="apellido" value="<?=$fila->Apellido?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="direccion" value="<?=$fila->Direccion?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="telefono" value="<?=$fila->Telefono?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="estado" value="<?=$fila->Estado?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="fechaIngreso" value="<?=$fila->FechaIngreso?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="password" value="<?=$fila->Password?>"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Modificar"/>
            <?php } ?>
        <!-- </form> -->
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        <a href="<?=base_url()?>">Volver</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cambié los name de los elementos del formulario, password por Password  por ejemplo y ahora actualiza, pero no muestra ningún mensaje.

Comment: no te devuelve ningun mensaje porque no le has puesto que lo haga. Usa el return de la función mod() (true o false) del update para determinar si se actualizaron los datos o no y mostrar un mensaje en consecuencia

Comment: ¿Osea que esto no sirve? return $this->db->update('tbl_cliente', $losDatos);  Discúlpame ¿Me podrías mostrar por favor el código? las modificaciones que tú harías  @JuanLuis

Comment: Donde quieres mostrar el mensaje tienes que hacer algo como esto: `echo $this->session->flashdata('actualizado');` o bien esto: `echo $this->session->flashdata('incorrecto');`

Comment: No te entiendo. Escoge tu un lugar y pónlo en mi código yo veo @A.Cedano. Por ejemplo, coge el controlador completo y modifícalo.

Comment: A ver yo no tengo experiencia trabajando con Codeigniter. Según tengo entendido este Framework usa el paradigma Modelo-Vista-Controlador. Entonces, en la Vista, deberías poner lo que te he dicho, una vez que el `UPDATE` se ha realizado. Imagino que sería después de haber enviado el formulario.

Comment: Pero eso tiene un problema, los datos van del formulario al controlador, de ahí al modelo y luego al controlador, si hay un problema por ahí, se mostraría erróneamente el mensaje de Registro actualizado.

Comment: Le puse un var_dump y me muestra false, pero los datos se actualizan en la base de datos. Este es el código en el modelo   $query = $this->db->update('tbl_cliente', $losDatos);
        if(is_object($query)){
          if($query->num_rows() == 1) // if the affected number of rows is one
          {
            return true;
           }
        }else{  
          return false;
        }

Comment: $config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

Answer (score 0):

A lo que me refiero es que la funcion **db->update** devuelve true o false si se ha ejecutado con éxito o no. Por tanto, tendrás que meter un condicional y actuar en consecuencia.

```
if($this->db->update('tbl_cliente', $losDatos)){
   echo "Datos actualizados";
} else {
  echo "Se produjo un error al actualizar los datos";
}
```

Comment: Funciona @Juan Luis pero me pone el mensaje en la parte de arriba del menú, ¿Hay forma de ponerlo en otro lugar?

Comment: Sustituye el "echo" por el "set_flash_data" como lo tenías antes